# Bruteforce and matching gives reverse/wrong results

Tags: java, android, opencv, matching, brute-force

I've been making an application where 2 images can be compared (2 pictures on my smartphone). There I use a FAST detector and FREAK descriptor on a limited amount of keypoints (i filtered out the 300 best ones according to the response). When I try to match it with BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING, it gives back 0 matches.

Matching happens with

```
        MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

        matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
        matcher.match(descriptors,descriptors1,matches);
        MatOfDMatch goedematches = new MatOfDMatch();

        double max_dist = 0;
        double min_dist = 100;
        //if (descriptors.cols() == descriptors1.cols())
        //{
        for( int i = 0; i < descriptors.rows(); i++ )
        { double dist = matches.toArray()[i].distance;
          if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
          if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
        }
        // should only draw good matches
       for( int i = 0; i < descriptors.rows(); i++ )
        {  MatOfDMatch temp = new MatOfDMatch();
           if( matches.toArray()[i].distance < 2*min_dist )
           {   temp.fromArray(matches.toArray()[i]);
               goedematches.push_back(temp); 
               }        
       // }
        }

       Log.d("LOG!", "Number of good matches= " + goedematches.size());
```

When I compare the image to itself, I get the following output. The output is 0x0 good matches.
[image]

```
05-02 15:52:30.325: D/LOG!(17866): Number of Descriptors image 1= 64x286
05-02 15:52:30.325: D/LOG!(17866): Number of Descriptors image 2= 64x286
05-02 15:52:30.325: D/LOG!(17866): description time elapsed 339 ms
05-02 15:52:30.555: D/LOG!(17866): Minimum distance = 0.0
05-02 15:52:30.560: D/LOG!(17866): Maximum distance= 0.0
05-02 15:52:30.560: D/LOG!(17866): Number of good matches= 0x0
```

When I use the same picture and one that has nothing to do with it, I get about 471 matches. There is something wrong inside the code, but I can't seem to see what's wrong (the code seems to reserve, cause everything that is the same isn't matched, and it's matched when it's completely different. Where is the code am I doing it wrong?)

**IMPORTANT:** Don't mind the red dots on the right picture, it's just an old picture I took when I drew the keypoints on the screen. It does not stand for the matching itself! It could be any other picture that has nothing to do with the first image.

[image]

```
05-02 16:03:06.120: D/LOG!(19025): Number of Descriptors image 1= 64x259
05-02 16:03:06.120: D/LOG!(19025): Number of Descriptors image 2= 64x286
05-02 16:03:06.420: D/LOG!(19025): Minimum distance= 93.0
05-02 16:03:06.420: D/LOG!(19025): Maximum distance = 183.0
05-02 16:03:06.420: D/LOG!(19025): Number of good matches= 1x286
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if( matches.toArray()[i].distance < 2*min_dist )
```

In your first case you compare the same images, so the value of min_dist is therefore 0
and your if statement will reject all matches as no distance is smaller than 0.

---

In your second case min_dist is 93*2=186 and since your maximum_distance is 183 this will lead to accepting all matches instead of rejecting them.

Consider looking into opencv computer vision cookbook in chapter 9 there is a good approach for keeping only good matches based on ratio and symmetry test.

Comment: Thank you for the good information, i'll be sure to look at it. Seems that I indeed need to find another approach. Is there a coockbook that uses Java wrappers as well, because it's all written for C, and I don't use the native part.

Comment: Here's a random idea: if i change the line to <= then it will accept the 0 as wel, and it doesn't just throw it away. Next I will make the filtering more strict by making the ` if( matches.toArray()[i].distance <= 2*min_dist )` from 2 to 1.5 or something?
Or is this a bad idea?

Comment: to everyone who reads this: it's a bad idea :D I still get more matches for a random picture then a picture that is quite similar

Comment: The syntax is very similar you just have to change OpenCV C++ variables such cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor>  to opencv4android counterparts DescriptorExtractor